# Dealing with asynchronous calls with Angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous, promise, rxjs

I am learning Angular and have the following question regarding async functions.
Please check the code below:

**This is the receiveInfo( ) method inside of my transferService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { CountryAllData } from 'src/app/Interfaces/CountryAllData';

export class TransferService {
  private apiResponse = new BehaviorSubject<CountryAllData[]>({} as CountryAllData[]);
  
  constructor() {}

  receiveInfo() {
    return this.apiResponse.asObservable();
  }
}
```

**I import the transferService inside of Chart Component and define the getApiResponse ( ) method:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TransferService } from 'src/app/Services/Transfer/transfer.service';
import { CountryAllData } from 'src/app/Interfaces/CountryAllData';


export class ChartComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

constructor(private transferService: TransferService) {}

  getApiResponse(after: Function) {
    this.transferService.receiveInfo().subscribe((d) => this.setApiResponse(d, after));
  }
```

I would like to call  `the after ()` function after setting the apiResponse using `this.setApiResponse`
So far I am doing it by passing the `after ()` function as a call back to the setApiResponse.

How could I do it using promises ?

Thank you

Comment: instead of converting it to promise, you can use take functionality. It'll automatically unsubscribe after n takes. ).pipe(take(1)).subscribe( res => ...). This acts as a promise

Answer (score 0):

You can do [`.toPromise()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/topromise) on the observable response from `getApiResponse` and `await` it and call it afterwards

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just saw that .toPromise( ) has been deprecated. I guess we need to use firstValueFrom( )